# which word to be used "tirades" or "diatribe"

Tags: word-usage

I am unable to figure out which word to be used to describe a situation of political accusations.

could some one explain how/under which circumstance tirade/diatribe to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *diatribe* is a single, often lengthy, angry verbal attack on someone (per Google's definition, for example).

A *tirade* is not necessarily directed at anyone, it's just an angry expression.

*Diatribe* would be more relevant if the accusations are directed towards definite targets like specific people or groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use either in most situations but I would argue that "diatribe" implies a longer and/or more formal speech.